# Error in creating an if statement in powershell with the hostname as a variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, syntax-error, hostname

In the script attached I am trying to rename a PC if the PC has a certain hostname. However, the script is proceeding anyway and bypasses the if/else statement.

What am I doing wrong? I am kind of new with Windows Powershell.

Thanks!

```
# get current computername
$hostname = hostname.exe
#$env:computername
If ( $hostname = "CLNT3100" ) 
{

#Get all the computers with CLNT3* and sort them with the 'highest client' on top. Then put them in newlist.txt
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'SamAccountName -like "CLNT3*"' | Select -Exp Name | Sort-Object -Descending >> C:\newlist.txt

#Put the text file in a variable and show the top line
$Text = Get-Content -Path C:\newlist.txt
#$Text[0]

#Trim CLNT for numbering
$Text1 = $Text[0].TrimStart("CLNT")

#Add 1 number to the previous CLNT
$Text2 = 1 + $Text1

#Add CLNT again to the new variable
$Text3 = "CLNT" + $Text2

#Rename the computer
Rename-Computer –computername minint –newname $Text3
}
Else
{
Write-Host "Computernaam is niet minint!!!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare if two values are equal in Powershell you have to use the `-eq`operator.
Check the Powershell [equality operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) to see the others like -gt, -lt etc, or type `man about_Comparison_Operators` in the PS shell.

Also, to learn Powershell I found [this free ebook](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx) to be very good.

Comment: OK, so it should be If ( $hostname -eq "CLNT3100" ) then?

Comment: Yes. It would be -eq / -like / -match . Depending on what you are after.